# locate a maven jar package in eclipse and open it

Tags: eclipse, maven

How to quickly locate a maven jar package in eclipse and open it in eclipse to view the class files in it. My maven project relies on more than 200 jars. I want to find spring-boot.jar and open it to view the source code, but this is very difficult in eclipse.

Comment: If you call a method, you can open that method with F3. This usually also works for methods in external JARs, as long as they provide source code.

Comment: And if you add the "Enhanced Class Decompiler" Eclipse plugin, you can see the decompiled code if the source code was not available.